# Zoom in animation effect is not working correctly using css

Tags: css

I have added css code for animation zoomin its working fine but the problem is i haven't written code for zoom out but the image is showing for both zoomin and zom out.

```
<div class="slotholder"><img src="http://www.server.com/fhdfsmile/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/slider01.jpg"></div>
.slotholder {
webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-webkit-animation: zoomin 0s ease-in infinite;
animation: zoomin 30s ease-in infinite;

 }
  @-webkit-keyframes zoomin {
  0% {transform: scale(1);}
  50% {transform: scale(1.5);}
  100% {transform: scale(1);}
   }
  @keyframes zoomin {
  0% {transform: scale(1);}
 50% {transform: scale(1.5);}
 100% {transform: scale(1);}
  }
```

i have written css for zoom in but it is coming for zoom out also.I dont want zoom out option only the image need to be zoomed.

Comment: Try removing `infinite` and change `zoomin` to: `0% {transform: scale(1);} 100% {transform: scale(1.5);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Changes

- Replace `infinite` with [`forwards`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction)
- `@keyframes` are progressive so when it was:

  ```
  @keyframes zoomin {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
      /* Changed to 1.25 */
      transform: scale(1.5);
    }
    100% {
      /* Changed to 1.5 */
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
  ```

  At the beginning `0%` it was normal size `scale(1)`, then halfway `50%` it was bigger `scale(1.5)`, but at the end `100%` it shrunk back down to normal size `scale(1)`.
- [`transform-origin: top left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) was added to position the image to avoid cropping.

---

### Demo

```css
.slotholder {
  animation: zoomin 10s ease-in forwards;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

@keyframes zoomin {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slotholder"><img src="https://smileaz.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/45/2018/07/types-of-dentures.jpg" width='300'></div>
```